# When moderators wield their privilege shouldn't it be clear why they did so?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In returning to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791031/generics-in-dbcontext-using-entity-framework) that I answered yesterday, I found that a moderator has intervened and closed the question.

I'm unhappy that moderation privileges were not used correctly in this case.

As far as I can see, the stated reason for closure does not correspond to anything that I can see in the question. *(the original closure reason was "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.", which has now been superseded by my dupehammer vote).*

So, how does that question (which has had minimal edits) qualify for the stated closure reason? I'm sure there's some logical reason that the moderator chose to intervene, but where the closure reason has specific wording that doesn't appear to correspond to problems in the question, wouldn't additional comments be appropriate?

Comment: Interesting that while I've garnered downvotes here, nobody has told me how my thinking is misguided.

Comment: @Oriol He said that the chosen close reason doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: No, I mean that when a close reason states certain reasons for closure, it should be clear how those reasons apply to the question. I don't see any relation to the closure reason stated, which in turn makes the moderation seem arbitrary.

Comment: Are you asking about this in general, or in the context of one specific question? Currently the title suggests the former, the body the latter. Could you please edit the question and title to clarify?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm asking specifically about this question, but in the larger context, when a privileged user steps in, my expectation is that they do so in a way that is educational to the person who is affected. The OP asked a clear question, yet the closure reason is rather unclear. Under these circumstances, it's my belief that moderators should go the extra distance to make their intent clear. I'll leave my question as is.

Comment: Why are you answering a duplicated? Why are you, a 68k rep user with gold badge, *answering a duplicated*? Why hasn't the moderator removed those answers?

Comment: @Braiam See my comments to NathanOliver's answer below.

Comment: @Braiam The lack of "specific-question" tag was deliberate because while the question concerns a specific question, it's actually a query about the responsibilities that a moderator bears when wielding their privileges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came to that question via the flags against the self non-answer. As far as I can could make out from reading it the non-answer claimed that it was resolved by something not clear from the question and not given in the other answers. I.e. the OP seems to have said that the problem lay elsewhere.

I'm happy to take feedback and reopen it if people think that's wrong but it read like a straight forward "question doesn't actually illustrate the real problem", in which case the close reason gives all the feedback it needed.

I'll reopen it now so the community can close as a duplicate though, but without hints from the community it's hard for me acting as a mod to find good dupe targets.

Comment: I took your hint and stepped up! Thanks @Flexo.

Answer (score 6):

Well the question did deserve to be closed and I can understand why the mod chose what he did.  All the solution required was the addition of the `class` keyword which is pretty basic and could have accidentally been left off by the OP.  It would kind of be like forgetting `typename` or `class` in a C++ template declaration.

It is also possible the now deleted answer that was posted by the OP and deleted by the same mod made the mod inclined to close it as a typo

> Thanks Spender and Kirill Shlenskiy. It was a quick catch. I missed to cast my object to class and by doing so, it has solved the problem.

To me the last sentence makes it look like it was a typo by the OP.

If you're unhappy with that closure then I feel it should still have been closed but as a dupe.  I admit I do not know much C# and have never answered a C# question but a simple google search for

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter

yields:

- [The type must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451120/the-type-must-be-a-reference-type-in-order-to-use-it-as-parameter-t-in-the-gen)
- [How to make a method generic when "type 'T' must be a reference type"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365134/how-to-make-a-method-generic-when-type-t-must-be-a-reference-type)
- [Why do I get "error: ... must be a reference type" in my C# generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992443/why-do-i-get-error-must-be-a-reference-type-in-my-c-sharp-generic-method)

Which all look like they could work.

Comment: In which case, a duplicate should have been flagged, no?

Comment: @spender Yes if you fell it is not a typo then the dupe closure should have been chosen.  I am a little surprised no one ever suggested it was a dupe in the almost hour it was as it seams like such an obvious dupe.

Comment: Indeed... perhaps I should have wielded my dupehammer instead of venturing an answer... However, this really isn't a typo, and the OP, upon returning to the question might be left rather confused. I'm all for a clean site, but I'm also very keen on transparent moderation. I feel that, in this case, the moderation has failed the OP and has the potential to leave the OP with a negative impression of our community.